# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Magento2 Error

Tags: product, magento-2.1, save

When i tried to save the product from Admin i am getting below error

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalog_product_category_cl' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`)

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataset = [
    [
        'entity_id' => 1,
        'attribute_id' => 1,
        'value' => 'maybe',
        'store_id' => 1
    ],
    [
        'entity_id' => 1,
        'attribute_id' => 1,
        'value' => 'maybe not',
        'store_id' => 2
    ],
    [
        'entity_id' => 1,
        'attribute_id' => 1,
        'value' => 'it\'s real',
        'store_id' => 3
    ]
];
$fields = [
    'entity_id',
    'attribute_id',
    'value',
    'store_id'
];

$connection = $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection(); // grab one connection object in any way
$connection->insertOnDuplicate(
    $connection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_int'),
    $dataset,
    $fields
);
```

above will create the proper `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE ...` query which can update the field if duplication in Primary key or UNIQUE index can be caused by the insert query